# Отправление запроса MySQL с изменением параметра в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

**Знаю, что это не по правилам сайта!!!**

Помогите пожалуйста написать запрос mysql

Мне надо скрипт запроса к mysql.

1. Ищем логин в базе.
2. Если существует, то продолжаем.
3. В таблице есть параметр "money" надо его заменить.
4. Делаем проверку, если там например значение **$balance**
       (100), а пользователь запросил
       **$minus** (150), то выдаем ошибку "недостаточно на балансе", если все
       есть, то заменяем число на другое.

Я приготовил уже переменные для подсчета:

```
$balance = $userinfo["money"];
$minus = $_POST["money"];
$otvet = $balace-$minus;
```

А потом в запросе на проверку надо вписать $otvet Вот только я не знаю как записать полностью скрипт

Comment: Например так:

    UPDATE 
        `tbl` 
    SET `money` = `money` - 3500 
    WHERE 
        `login` = 'some_login' AND (`money` - 3500) > 0;

Comment: А вы бы не могли написать полностью скрипт?

Comment: Что значит весь? Вместо **'some_login'** подставляете логин пользователя, вместо **3500** - сумму, которую надо снять. Вот и весь запрос.

Comment: А что 0 в конце запроса обозначает?

Comment: Ответ на комментарий я оставил ниже в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
....................
$login = $_POST['login']; // или измените на свое хранилище логина юзверя
$s = $userinfo["money"];  // баланс, но откуда?
$y = 100; // Если это текущий баланс из базы, то это лишняя переменная
$x = $s-$y; // существует ли $s ???

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = `money` - $x WHERE `login` = '$login' AND (`money` - $x) > 0") or die("Запрос с ошибкой ".mysql_error());

?>
```

Попробуйте вместо предыдущего поставить следующий запрос, если не появится новой записи в базе, значит у вас проблемы с mysql, если появится, то виной те чудо переменные, которые вы пытаетесь использовать

```
$login = 'cnofss';

 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = 100500 WHERE `login` = $login") or die("Запрос с ошибкой ".mysql_error());;
```

Comment: Весь мой скрипт, кроме него больше нет ни чего, представьте, что 1 пустая страницы, на ней только вот этот скрипт и все.

`<?php  
$host="localhost";
$user="admin";
$password="12345";
$db="baza";
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("MySQL сервер недоступен!".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Нет соединения с БД".mysql_error());

$login = 'cnofss';

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = 100500 WHERE `login` = $login") or die("Запрос с ошибкой ".mysql_error());;

 ?>`

Comment: Извините. Забыл заключить $login в апострафы:

mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = 100500 WHERE `login` = '$login'")

Comment: Уряяяя... Работает!!!! Ну наконецто решили проблему :D

Answer (score 0):

http://prntscr.com/2ll2ti Выдает ошибку.
Вот весь скрипт

```
    <?php 
    $host="localhost";
$user="admin";
$password="12345";
$db="baza";
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("MySQL сервер недоступен!".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Нет соединения с БД".mysql_error());

    $s = $userinfo["money"];
    $y = 100;
    $x = $s-$y;

    UPDATE 
        `users` 
    SET `money` = `money` - $x 
    WHERE 
        `login` = '$s' AND (`money` - $x) > 0;

        ?>
```

Comment: Смешнее способа послать запрос к БД пока не встречал :)) Вообще-то для передачи запросов и обработки результатов, возвращенных сервером mysql существуют спец. ф-и типа mysql_query(), mysql_fetch_assoc() и т.д.

Comment: Изменил подклчение

Comment: Подключение как раз-таки в норме